# Deleting Textboxes in a C# Form deletes only half in foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, textbox, controls

I'm trying to delete textboxes through codes, but when I'm trying to delete the controls in the form, it only deletes half of them. So, every time I click the button, half of the textboxes are deleted, then the half of it when I click it again until there's no more textboxes.

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
foreach (Control t in properties_panel.Controls)
                {
                    if (t is TextBox)
                    {
                        this.Controls.Remove(t);
                        t.Dispose();

                    }

                }
```

Also, is this the correct way to delete control objects?

Comment: what's properties_panel ? Does your properties_panel contains all the textboxes?\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're not supposed to modify an enumerator while iterating!**

When you remove an item from the controls collection in the middle of the foreach loop on that same collection, you've changed where the `MoveNext()` call in the enumerator will end up next. You need to do something to gather all of the textbox references first separately from the enumerator:

```
var boxes = properties_panel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
foreach (var t in boxes)
{
    properties_panel.Controls.Remove(t);
    t.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just starting in c# visual studio. Anyway this answered both of my questions :)